# What is the standard rule for running 12-1?

Tags: phase-10

In Phase 10, in specific phases, you have to complete "run"s of cards, like this:

> 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11

But recently I've come across the discussion whether this is a valid run?

> 11, 12, 1, 2..

According to the rulebook, you have to agree on this before the game (elsewise, you can play runs like this). 
But according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_10#Definitions):

> Runs can go from one to twelve.

In my understanding, this does **not** include from twelve to one!

What is the common agreement for this?

Answer (score 7):

Here is my opinion.

1) I have **never seen it** played where 11, 12, 1, 2 was allowed.

The official printed rules say...

> RUNS: A run is made of four or more cards **numbered in order**. EXAMPLE: Part of Phase 2 requires a run of four, which could be “3,” “4,” “5,” “6.” The cards may be in any combination of colors.

2) The official iPad version of the game does NOT allow 11, 12, 1, 2. (I tried to make sure)

3) I found an updated version of the rules on line...

> Run: A run (similar to a straight) is made of four or more cards numbered in order. The cards do not have to be the same color. A run may not go in order of 11, 12, 1, 2; this is an illegal play. Runs must stop at 12 and only start at 1.

So, I would say that 11,12,1,2 is NOT allowed.

Comment: Could you please link to the rules you found online?

Comment: http://ogres.wikia.com/wiki/Phase_10

Comment: You're welcome. Are the rules you linked to the "official printed rules" or the "updated version of the rules on line"? You could edit your post to have a hyperlink for the one you mean.

Comment: I'd say its rare when rules list what cannot be done outside of FAQ (sometimes even then, "F" after all=)).  I have seen other games where rules specifically say they allow "wrapping" like questioned.  I feel like a list of games is tangential but this fact in general worth mentioning.  +1 to this answer.